# teacher gave a task to add 2 signed very long int using linked lists and input number as strings. the algo I used, which other better algo can I use?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

First I created structure to create linked list. then created class and appropriate functions to perform certain task. Which other approach or algorithm can I use to make my solution efficient and faster in context of time complexity?

I used doubly linked list for my solution. can I do this using singly or circular linked list?

```
class GiantInt
{
    public:
        node* head;
        node* tail;
        int size; 
        GiantInt()
        {
            head = tail = NULL;
        }
        //~GiantInt();

        void Insert_at_head(int value)
        {
            node* temp = new node(value);

            if(head == NULL)
            {
                head = tail = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                head->previous = temp;
                temp->next = head;
                head = temp;
            }

            size++;
        }

        void Insert_at_tail(int value)
        {
            node* temp = new node(value);

            if(tail == NULL)
            {
                head = tail = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                tail->next = temp;
                temp->previous = tail;
                tail = temp;
            }

            size++;
        }

        void display()
        {
            node* temp = head;

            while(temp != NULL)
            {
                cout << temp->data;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }

        int length()
        {
            return size;
        }

        void Addition(GiantInt* a, GiantInt* b)
        {
            int c = 0, s;
            GiantInt* a1 = new GiantInt(*a);
            GiantInt* b1 = new GiantInt(*b);

            this->head = NULL;
            this->tail = NULL;
            this->size = 0;

            while (a1->tail != NULL || b1->tail != NULL)
            {
                if(a1->tail != NULL && b1->tail != NULL)
                {
                    s = ((a1->tail->data) + (b1->tail->data) + c) % 10;
                    c = ((a1->tail->data) + (b1->tail->data) + c) / 10;
                    a1->tail = a1->tail->previous;
                    b1->tail = b1->tail->previous;    
                }
                else if(a1->tail == NULL && b1->tail != NULL)
                {
                    s = ((b1->tail->data) + c) % 10;
                    c = ((b1->tail->data) + c) / 10;
                    b1->tail = b1->tail->previous;
                }
                else if(a1-> tail != NULL && b1->tail == NULL)
                {
                    s = ((a1->tail->data) + c) % 10;
                    c = ((a1->tail->data) + c) / 10;
                    a1->tail = a1->tail->previous;
                }
                Insert_at_head(s);
            }

            if( c != 0)
                Insert_at_head(c);
        }
};

int main()
{
    GiantInt* m = new GiantInt();
    GiantInt* n = new GiantInt();
    GiantInt* sum = new GiantInt();
    
    string number1, number2;
    
    cout<<" Enter numbers to add: ";
    cin >> number1 >> number2;

    for(int i = 0; i < number1.length(); i++)
    {
        m->Insert_at_tail(number1.at(i) - '0');
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < number2.length(); i++)
    {
        n->Insert_at_tail(number2.at(i) - '0');
    }

    cout << "Sum: " << endl;
    sum->Addition(m, n);
    sum->display();
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *which other better algo can I use?* -- Regular arrays or strings.  There is no need to implement all of this complexity to add large integers -- it's like using your foot to scratch the top of your head.   To add, a linked list is wasteful in terms of memory and cache-friendliness.

Comment: And as far as time and space complexity, using arrays to store the digits takes linear time with linear space to do "big integer" addition.

Comment: Our Professor gave us an assignment to do so.

Comment: *Which other approach or algorithm can I use* -- Your current implementation leaks memory.  Also what other approach is there except to go left to right (or right to left), going a column of digits at a time, similar to how you learned to add back in elementary school?  If there is another way, then that has nothing to do with linked lists.  The point is that it is much easier and less expensive to go through a list of digits using a simple array, but the approach of going through the list of digits is the same regardless of the data structure you use.

Comment: thank you @PaulMcKenzie for explanation!

Comment: linked list makes sense only if you do addition in-place as you can insert and remove digits without moving the rest of data ... however cyclic ring buffer can do this too with the benefits of simple array instead of linked list ... one might think its waste-full as such buffer must be pre-allocated to bigger size but your linked list is multiple times bigger ... From algorithmic aspect I assume you store base 10 digits in your list ... how about storing base `1000000000` digits instead (assuming 32bit integers)?

Comment: If your teacher gave you the assignment to use linked lists, then please make clear in the question that you *have* to use linked lists. As it is phrased now, it sounds like you are looking for *any* way to get a more efficient algorithm, and the answer to that is "stop using linked lists".

Comment: As to the question whether you can use singly linked lists instead of doubly linked lists, the answer is: yes.

Comment: Actually @trincot I am new to this platform, so I may make some mistake  in asking question